# UITableViewCell image is not showing properly on condition when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have condition to show image for only few rows. But when I scroll, the image is shown for other random rows as well. Below is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        //var data = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        if let data = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
            if let name = data.objectForKey("NAME") as? String{
                cell.textLabel?.text = name
            }
            if completedTrainings.contains((data.objectForKey("MENU_ID") as? Int)!) {
                cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell.bounds.width-110), y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CORRECT")
            } 
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Image should only appears if menu id exist in completed trainings but on scroll it appears on some random cells as well. Also the image is coming at the left but it should come at right. How can I move it to right?

Comment: Create custom Table View Cell, if you want to place image on right.

Comment: Add this line,
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage()

Comment: Cells are reused, you have to set all UI elements to a certain state by adding `else` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `image` is the optional for `UIImageView` u can set the image to `nil` if u dont want to display the image for example in your code, as vadian suggested

```
     cell.imageView?.image = nil //reset the cell image first
     cell.textLabel?.text  = "" 
     if let data = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
        if let name = data.objectForKey("NAME") as? String{
            cell.textLabel?.text = name
            cell.imageView?.image = nil //add this line
        }
        if completedTrainings.contains((data.objectForKey("MENU_ID") as? Int)!) {
            cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell.bounds.width-110), y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CORRECT")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to create you own custom UITableViewCell subclass either in the storyboard or in a nib file and register for that nib file in you view controller. This will give you the option to design whatever cell you want with any layout. The reason why you see this image on random cells is because your cells are being reused and in case you don't find the image (if completedTrainings.contains) you don't set the imageView hidden or set it's image to be an empty image (maybe a special image you have for that case).

Answer (score 1):

While dealing with reuseable cell. Try to use if and else both. Only if can make issues like that.